# Problem in implementing search filter in data tables in react

Tags: reactjs, search, filter, datatable

I am implementing a search filter feature in my react data table. You can see the UI [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3iXg.png) for a better understanding of code.
I implemented it to search the data by names initially. (I will implement it to search in all columns later). It seems that the filter search isn't working. I am new to react and I did everything correct upto my Knowledge but I am still missing something.

Here is my **Bookings2.js** (Table is implemented in this)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../static/Bookings.css';
import {BsFilterRight} from "react-icons/bs";

const Bookings2= ()=>{
    const[Bookings, setBooking]=useState([]);
    const[search, setSearch]=useState("");

    useEffect(()=>{
        loadUsers();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        setBooking(
            Bookings.filter(Booking=>{
                return Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(Booking.name.toLowerCase())
            })
        )
    }, [search, Bookings]);


    const loadUsers= async()=>{
        const result =await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Bookings");
        setBooking(result.data.reverse());
    };

    const deleteUser=async id => {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/Bookings/${id}`);
        loadUsers();
    }

    return(
        <div className="Booking-page-container">
            <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Bookings2 Page</h2>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped border shadow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" colSpan={5}>
                        <BsFilterRight/> &nbsp;
                            <input 
                                placeholder=" search....."
                                onChange={e=>setSearch(e.target.value)}
                            />  
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
          
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Consultant</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {Bookings.map((Booking,index)=>(
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{index+1}</th>
                            <td>{Booking.name}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.consultant}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.email}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Link class="btn btn-primary mr-2" to={`/Bookings/view/${Booking.id}`}>View</Link>
                                <Link class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2" to={`/Bookings/edit/${Booking.id}`}>Edit</Link>
                                <Link class="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>deleteUser(Booking.id)}>Delete</Link>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Bookings2;
```

Comment: You're mixing up your state values. You're using `setSearch` when creating a filtered list of bookings inside the effect, you should be using `setBooking`. And in your JSX your'e doing `search.map` to render the table, but you should be mapping over the bookings you fetched inside `loadUsers`, right?

Comment: Why does the `search` variable default to an array?

Comment: @Jayce444 I changed the code as suggested. But now data is not rendering

Comment: @codemonkey  made it default to string

Comment: There's other errors too. For instance, this code: `return Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(Booking.name.toLowerCase())` makes no sense, you're seeing if the book names contains....itself. It should be `return Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(search..toLowerCase())`. Also, you have `Bookings` as a dependency to that second effect that calls `setBooking`, so it will call itself in a loop. And maybe some other errors I missed. Are you doing `console.log(Bookings)` in the body of the function and seeing that it's loading the data from the API as expected?

Answer (score 0):

There may be other inconsistencies and I would be happy to work with you on those, but the first thing that stands out is this:

```
        setBooking(
            Bookings.filter(Booking=>{
                return Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(Booking.name.toLowerCase())
            })
        )
```

It should be:

```
     if(search.length){
       setBooking(
            Bookings.filter(Booking =>
                Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
            )
        )
     }
```

This assumes, of course, that your `Bookings` array is an array of objects that have a `name` key in them.

**EDIT:** Create a variable called `bookings_array` and put it outside the component:

```
...
let bookings_array = [];
const Bookings2= ()=>{
    const[Bookings, setBooking]=useState([]);
    const[search, setSearch]=useState("");
...
```

Then, change your `loadUsers` to:

```
    const loadUsers= async()=>{
        const result =await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Bookings");
        bookings_array = result.data.reverse();
        setBooking(bookings_array);
    };
```

And then change what's inside your `useEffect` to:

```
     if(search.length){
       setBooking(
            Bookings.filter(Booking =>
                Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
            )
        )
     }else{
       setBooking(bookings_array)
     }
```

Comment: Yes it worked fine but it  came up with another problem that  when i enter input in search field then it shows the filtered results but when I remove the input from the search field it still shows the filtered results only.

Comment: I got what you did but I was saying that I want to search the table every time I make changes in search field. The above code will only render the table again when I make search field empty completely but not search again if I press backspace once. I hope you got what I want to say. Please help  in that.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525046/problem-in-implementing-search-filter-in-reactjs-trigger-issues/66525115#66525115) additional problem I am facing with the code you suggested. It will be really helpful if it is also fixed.