# Problem in implementing Search Filter in Reactjs- Trigger issues

Tags: reactjs, search, datatable, react-hooks

I am implementing a react data table with a search filter in it to search the rows. You can see the UI [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewpGw.png) for a better understanding of code. I implemented it to search the rows by names initially. (I will implement it to search in all columns later).

As you can see in the UI that there are three entries at top named "Kamakshi", "Kanika" and "Kanika" respectively. When I type "Kam" in the search box then [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKh9g.png) result is shown. Now on pressing backspace my input becomes "ka", which means my search result should show three rows of "Kamakshi", "Kanika" and "Kanika". But there are no changes.

I want to trigger the search filter everytime there is a change in input. I passed it as dependency in useEffect but it didn't worked.

Here is my **Bookings2.js** (Table is implemented in this)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../static/Bookings.css';
import {BsFilterRight} from "react-icons/bs";

let bookings_array = [];    
const Bookings2= ()=>{
    const[Bookings, setBooking]=useState([]);
    const[search, setSearch]=useState("");

    useEffect(()=>{
        loadUsers();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(search.length){
        setBooking(
                Bookings.filter(Booking =>
                    Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
                )
            )
        }else{
            setBooking(bookings_array)
        }
    }, [search, Bookings]);


    const loadUsers= async()=>{
        const result =await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Bookings");
        bookings_array=result.data.reverse();
        setBooking(bookings_array);
    };

    const deleteUser=async id => {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/Bookings/${id}`);
        loadUsers();
    }

    return(
        <div className="Booking-page-container">
            <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Bookings2 Page</h2>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped border shadow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" colSpan={5}>
                        <BsFilterRight/> &nbsp;
                            <input 
                                placeholder=" search....."
                                onChange={e=>setSearch(e.target.value)}
                            />  
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
          
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Consultant</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {Bookings.map((Booking,index)=>(
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{index+1}</th>
                            <td>{Booking.name}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.consultant}</td>
                            <td>{Booking.email}</td>
                            <td>
                                <Link class="btn btn-primary mr-2" to={`/Bookings/view/${Booking.id}`}>View</Link>
                                <Link class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2" to={`/Bookings/edit/${Booking.id}`}>Edit</Link>
                                <Link class="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>deleteUser(Booking.id)}>Delete</Link>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Bookings2;
```

Comment: This is because you are not storing the **original** array anywhere. When you filter the Bookings array, the original, full list is lost. You should store that original list you fetch somewhere (probably in a ref) and then filter that original list when you change the search, not the current one (which is itself already filtered)

Comment: I got your point but it will be really helpful if you can show me by doing changes in the code. As I am a beginner and still learning I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Jayce444 He is storing the original in bookings_array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of filtering the state array, try filtering the original, which is stored in `bookings_array`. So change this:

```
if (search.length) {
    setBooking(
        Bookings.filter(Booking =>
            Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )
    )
} else {
    setBooking(bookings_array)
}
```

to:

```
if (search.length) {
    setBooking(
        bookings_array.filter(Booking =>
            Booking.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
        )
    )
} else {
    setBooking(bookings_array)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a change happens in the search, you are removing things from Bookings...but you do not add them back in when new changes roll in, which is why they are not returning on a backspace. You need to run your `loadUsers` function again if you want to load your original Bookings back in to be filtered.

Comment: Please show it by code. I got your point but code will be really helpful as I am a beginner.

Comment: Should i call the loadUsers agian in search useEffect?